# Turn off tag checking "<%=" in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Using PhpStorm as my editor. I have something like the following:

```
<script type="text/template" id="during_call">
    Login in as <%= name %>
</script>
```

PhpStorm doesn't like the `<%= =>` tags and mucks up the highlighting for the rest of the source file. Is there a way to get PhpStorm to ignore just the `<%= =>` tags?

I'm finding it very difficult to search in google as it ignores the those tags in the search term.

Comment: It works in conjunction with the underscore.js library. You can use templates. Just wondering if there is a way for phpstorm to ignore these tags.

Comment: PhpStorm cannot just "ignore something" -- it all should be parsed otherwise it is treated as an error. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-679 -- have a look at comments there -- you should find  workarounds (may need to install additional plugin). BTW -- the content of `<script type="text/template"` tags should be treated as plain text so no warnings on `<%=` tags should be given -- it works just fine here in 2016.1.1 in .html file

Comment: So I guess at the moment there isn't anything that can be set to get PhpStorm to not muck up the highlight etc oh well, thanks

Comment: The files are php. I'm thinking that's probably what's confusing PhpStorm

Comment: Please share example of such file. I've tried putting your same code before or after PHP code block (in .php file, obviously) and it also worked. Maybe there is some significant difference in yours (mine was simple test code). Please also state your IDE version.

Comment: Using PhpStorm 2016.1.1  As a way to show what's happening for me, I've taken a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/1C0KP2r.png Here you can see as soon as PhpStorm encounters the first ```<%``` it just seems to break it. Any code after this point does not get checked, cannot be formatted etc etc

Comment: Unfortunately screenshot is useless here -- it does not give any useful info to diagnose the issue. Please share whole file (you may simplify it by removing other stuff/changing text as long as it can still reproduce the issue. It may also be that some 3rd party plugin is causing this -- try disabling them for now to see if anything will be changed. Also - when posting screenshots -- please always use unmodified either Default or Darcula color schema -- custom colors may hide some details/warnings.

Comment: You can see where PhpStorm stops. Doesn't matter which template blocks appears first, it always stops at the first instance of ```<%```. I just changed the theme to Darcula and it made no difference - it stops at exactly the same position as shown in the screenshot. I just have whatever addons PhpStorm came with. What's the best way to post the file?

Comment: Maybe try 2016.1.2 .. or even 2016.2 EAP build and see if it's any better there. As for file -- either share it via Google Drive/Dropbox or any other similar file sharing service